# Как сохранять объект типа Marker?

Tags: android, карты

Обрабатываю события нажатия на маркеры карты и столкнулся с такой вот трудностью. Как я понял этот тип не Parcelable и не Serializable. При повороте экрана теряются значения. Как можно решить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сохраняйте [`MarkerOptions`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions), он `Parcelable`. А потом создавайте `Marker` на его основе.